# What's wrong with this JSON code?

Tags: json

I'm new to JSON and I'm trying to store this data in an array, I'm not sure if this is a good way of doing this or not but I can't understand why this is invalid.

```
"IDs": [116, {"record":{"A":943}}, 234, 38793, {"record":{"B":456}}]
```

I've received this error message but I don't understand it.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fpqW.png)

Comment: Looks to me it starts with a key, try placing curly brackets `{}` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed main parentheses:

```
{
    "IDs": [116, {
        "record": {
            "A": 943
        }
    }, 234, 38793, {
        "record": {
            "B": 456
        }
    }]
}
```

This is valid according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)